# Keeping threads for tasks in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I'm making an application in C#. This application should do some computation based on user-input.
This computation is rather heavy so I've made it concurrent with tasks, this works rather well and my performance has improved.
My problem however is that the threads used by these task get killed if they are not used fast enough. So if the user waits like 30 seconds before the next input the threads get killed and need to be restarted.

The restarting of the threads however cost relatively a lot of time. is it possible to keep those threads open or should I just not use tasks for this?

If you need additional information just ask!

**EDIT**

```
 int size = 10;
        Task[] htasks = new Task[size];
        Task[] vtasks = new Task[size];
        Semaphore[] vsemaphores = new Semaphore[size * 2 - 1];
        Semaphore[] hsemaphores = new Semaphore[size * 2 - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < size * 2 - 1; i++)
        {
            vsemaphores[i] = new Semaphore(1, 2);
            hsemaphores[i] = new Semaphore(1, 2);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            int local = i;
            htasks[local] = new Task(() => CalculateVSeams(ref hsemaphores, local, workingWidth, workingHeight));
            vtasks[local] = new Task(() => CalculateHSeams(ref vsemaphores, local, workingWidth, workingHeight));

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            htasks[i].Start();
            vtasks[i].Start();
        }
        Task.WaitAll(htasks);
        Task.WaitAll(vtasks);
```

some benchmarks: these are times of operations see how the first one takes way more time.
11031
180
183
179
220

Then if I don't do something for a while I get this in my output:
The thread 0xfbc has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1e2c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1ed8 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x1ee4 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
and a bunch more. Then the benchmark returns similar results.

Comment: What is killing those threads? Threads usually don't kill themselves ;). And how are you starting the tasks? With `Task.Run`?

Comment: We really need to see how you are approaching this to be able to offer any help. Sample of code?

Comment: This sound strange. Post a working pice of code that recreates you problem, then we can help you

Comment: Isn't this just the normal behaviour of threads used in tasks that don't get used for a while?

Comment: it might be but in that case I would like something with out that behaviour because it's killing to have 11secs waiting time for userinput

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your tasks are using the default scheduler for your current environment. (which is most likely the C# ThreadPool). You can get this scheduler through the `Task.Factory.Scheduler` property.

The threadpool will start and stop threads for executing tasks as required by it's current workload. This is why you see the stopped threads. Normally this isn't any problem. Even if it has to start 4 threads this will take some milliseconds and nowhere near 11 seconds. For the first run of your program it will also be slower due to the initial JIT compilation and VM warmup. But even that won't make such a large differenct.

Maybe you have another problem in your code? Or are you including the users idle time into the first measurement by accident?

If you are not satisfied with the schedulers behavior you can create tasks which use another scheduler by creating a `TaskFactory` and passsing it another scheduler and create your tasks from that. You will need to implement a custom scheduler for that. You could create one that has a fixed number of threads and then assigns all new tasks in round-robin fashion on it. But normally the C# ThreadPool should be really fine.

Comment: Still not sure what caused the 11 seconds,(wasn't wrong timing, stopwatch is created after userinput) but after looking at the Threadpool, I put the minimumthreads higher and even though the first is still a bit slower its been reduced to under 250 ms vs 120ms otherwise. this is good enough for me!